# When parse xml via c# get "\ / " or so on

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I parse config file via Linq.
File like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Path Name="Config file">
  <PathToHelpTopic>"/Files/HelpTopics.xml"</PathToHelpTopic>
  <PathToFiles>"http://system-help"</PathToFiles>
```

And try to parse:

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(helpTopicPath);

 var path = from item in doc.Descendants("PathToHelpTopic")
            select item.Value;
 foreach (var p in path)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(p);
    return p;
 }
```

But p= "\"/Files/HelpTopics.xml\""  .

How get result string like /Files/HelpTopics.xml  ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, you want to trim off all the double quotes from the value:

```
var path = from item in doc.Descendants("PathToHelpTopic")
           select item.Value.Trim('"');
```